# why JsonElement is struct type?

Tags: c#, json, .net, system.text.json

in many JSON parsers, the element of json is presented as object(reference) type.

However in C#, System.Text.Json `JsonElement` is `struct` type. Why JsonElement is struct type?

I'm worried about this could cause unnecessary memory copy.
What if JsonElement has very big data? what if JsonElement has array that contains over 1000 objects?

Comment: The majority of information it holds is placed inside a `JsonDocument` property which is a class. So it's not an issue as you'll only copy the reference of that `JsonDocument` when you pass your `JsonElement` into a method or similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Document/JsonElement.cs) you'll see that `JsonElement` is very lightweight. It only has two fields: a reference to the containing document, and an index into the document. In particular, it *doesn't* directly contain all the data for the element.

This *avoids* creating a lot of memory churn, as it's efficient to (for example) iterate over all the elements in a document, without it having to create large numbers of objects.